# How to make bash script run with a latency (i.e. wait 1 sec at each iterations)?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have this bash script;

```
for (( i = 1 ; i <= 160 ; i++ )); do
  qsub myccomputations"${i}".pbs
done
```

Basically, I would prefer if there was a 1 second delay between each iteration. The reason is that at each iterations, it sends the program file `mycomputation"${i}$.pbs` to a core node for solving. The motivation is that solving in this instance involves the use of pseudo random numbers and the RNG I use (R's) uses CPU time as seed.

So how to you ask bash to

```
for (( i = 1 ; i <= 160 ; i++ )); do
  wait 1 sec    
  qsub myccomputations"${i}".pbs
done
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Simply use `sleep 1` in Bash.

```
for (( i = 1 ; i <= 160 ; i++ )); do
  sleep 1
  qsub myccomputations"${i}".pbs
done
```

Comment: you can use floating point number if you want to sleep less than 1 second

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve what your topic suggests, you should use 'at'.

See

```
      man at
```

for more information.

Comment: thank you Olli. Indeed, i will rewrite the title, so it corresponds to the question, for future queries.

Comment: `at` will not suspend a loop for a specific duration, but set a program / script for execution at a specific time.