# Open Multiple Apps with one Click KDE Desktop

Tags: kde, startup, desktop-environments, kde-apps, multiple-instances

I have 24 Folders with 24 *.exe files (all the same name) I want to open this Apps with one click.
In windows I have a little programm which allows me to set a time delay, let´s say 2-3 seconds in between each file to open, which is good for Windows...

Does a solution for Linux (KDE Desktop) esxist?

Many Thanks!!!

Comment: EXE files will they even run in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you heard something like shell scripting?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli yes, I heard of it, but can´t programm it...so if someone can explain how to do it...that would be awesome :-) !

Comment: @David yes, but that was not the answer to my question :-)

Comment: Sorry, we do not write scripts here upon request. However, please see this for example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/26818/how-to-make-bash-script-run-with-a-latency-i-e-wait-1-sec-at-each-iterations

Comment: Please educate yourself about shell scripts using the online documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single script that will launch the different programs, so you can launch them all in one go just by launching the script.

A very quick and simple example of a script that would launch three programs with a delay of 2 seconds in between would be:

```
#!usr/bin/env bash
/Folder2/App1.exe &
sleep 2
/Folder2/App2.exe &
sleep 2
/Folder3/App3.exe &
```

- The programs should be started in the background. Otherwise, the next program will start only when the first one has finished. This is achieved by adding `&` to the end of the command.
- The `sleep` command is used to introduce a delay before launching the next program.

Make the script executable (Right-click in the file manager, then "Properties") and put it in a folder `.local/bin` under your home folder. `.local` is a hidden folder because the name starts with a dot. You can display it in the file manager by checking "Show hidden files". From then onwards, you will be able to launch the script simply by typing its name in the terminal or in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> run dialog.

To launch that script with a single click, you can create a [custom `.desktop` launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78730/how-do-i-add-a-custom-launcher) for it and put that in `.local/share/applications` (`.local` is a hidden folder in your home folder). A launcher in that folder will automatically appear in the application menu, and can be pinned to a dock as a favorite or placed on the desktop for quick access.

Comment: wow! Thank You so much @vanadium ! I will try this and report :-) very nice of you!!!